# Pythagorean triplets program

Tags: c

I have written a program that should be rather simple but on execution, it is not giving the wanted results. Even when debugging the program, I guess I found the error (getting stuck in the first if condition) but I'm not able to solve it (my inexperience perhaps). Anyways, this program, which should have been frugal, took 3 days whereas I expected it to take mere hours. Please help me with guiding me where I'm going wrong and how to solve it.
Here is the code

```
/*WAP to read pre entered no. of ints. consider only +ve and print the pythagorean triplets in them.*/
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c,p,pp,count=0,a;
    printf("How many entries to accept?\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the nos.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&c);
        if (c<0)    //skip -ve nos.
        {       
            continue;
        }
        if (count==0) 
        {
            pp=c;
            count++;
        }
        else if (count==1)
        {
            p=c;
            count++;
        }
        else if ((pp*pp)+(p*p)==(c*c))  //Tracking count not necesarry after first three
        {
            printf("Pythagorean triplet found\n");
            printf("%d %d %d",pp,p,c);
            pp=p;
            p=c;
        }
    }
    
return 0;
}
```

The main objective is to first scan a no. to signify the inputs to be read. Then scan the inputs, separated by a space or enter, in a loop which will only accept the no. of inputs stated before. It should neglect any -ve entries. It should print out the Pythagorean triplet if it encounters one, in a consecutive manner i.e. the triplet should appear one after the other & not randomly. **We have to do the task without using arrays.**

sample input is (you can consider any)(all given through the terminal)
(no. of entries)

> 6

> 1 -1 3 4 -4 5
> (Here it will ignore -1 & -4)

expected output will be

> Pythagorean triplet found

> 3 4 5

I am still learning so sorry for the elaborate program.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on the wanted result. What should this program do? What input was it given? What was the output and what is the expected result?

Comment: The main objective is to first scan a no. to signify the inputs to be read. Then scan the inputs, separated by a space or enter, in a loop which will only accept the no. of inputs stated before. It should neglect any -ve entries. It should print out the Pythagorean triplet if it encounters one, in a consecutive manner i.e. the triplet should appear one after the other & not randomly

Comment: I guess you should either read all three numbers in a single `scanf` or reset `count` when the third is read. In any case, don't ignore the value returned by `scanf`.

Comment: @Bob__ If I'm understanding what you're suggesting, I would perhaps need a dynamic array for that. I missed adding (I'll edit the question too) we have to of the task without using arrays. If that is not what you were suggesting, please could you explain your suggestion more elaborately?

Comment: I mean three *variables*: `... for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) { int a, b, c; int r = scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c); if ( r != 3 ) {/*input error*/)} ... if (a*a + b*b == c*c) {/* found triple*/} ... }`

Comment: @Bob__ tried this. It just scans 3 nos. What if we enter more than three?

Comment: So you read 'n' lots of three numbers and have to say if each one is a pythagorean triple, is that right

Comment: can you past the input file please

Answer (score 0):

since I cant see the input file I dont know if the values are sorted, since we need to identify which is the hypotenuse, makes it a bit more fiddly.

Also not clear what 'skip negatives' means. Does it mean

- that we might see 3 -6 4 5 and say 'yes 3,4,5' is a triple
- that we might see 3 -4 5 and say yes 3 4 5
- or that we might see 3 -4 5 and simply ignore the whole set

I have assumed the first one

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("How many entries to accept?\n");
    int a;
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {
        printf("bad input\n");
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("Enter the nos.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        int sides[3] = { 0 };
        int max = 0; // longest side length -> hypot
        
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            int c;
            
            if (scanf("%d", &c) != 1) {
                printf("bad input\n");
                return (-1);
            }
            if (c < 0)    //skip -ve nos.
                j--; // try again
            else {
                if (c > max) {
                    max = c;
                }
                sides[j] = c;
            }
        }
        int hyp = max * max; // hypotenuse squared
        int adjTot = 0;      // adj sides squared total
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (sides[j] == max)
                continue;
            adjTot += sides[j] * sides[j];
        }
        if (adjTot == hyp)
            printf("%d %d %d is py\n", sides[0], sides[1], sides[2]);
        else
            printf("%d %d %d isnt py\n", sides[0], sides[1], sides[2]);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since you say you are reading from a file it just exits if there is non numeric data

Comment: Thank you for the answer but you have used arrays and we are not supposed to use arrays. Anyways I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: made edits to incorporate what was missing and you pointed out..Anything further needed please let me know..

Comment: @P_K I misread the question, I though it said you must use arrays.Oops